# How to set the "Version" of an "Installed Update" in the Control Panel's "Add or Remove Programs"

Tags: windows-installer, version, installshield, addremoveprograms

I've created an MSI installation file using InstallShield 2010. After I've installed it, if I go to the "Add or Remove Programs" / "Programs and Features" in the Windows Control Panel I can see my program's entry and it also display the program's version.

I then created an update (patch/hotfix/QFE) using InstallShield 2010. After installing the MSP file, I click "View installed updates" and see my an entry for my patch but the version field is empty.

*How do populate the version of that installed update using InstallShield or the MSI API?*

See this screen shot for an example of what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do this by building a newer version of your msi (set to the higher version number you want to report), and then building a differential patch between the original msi and the new one.

The patch should take on the version of the newer msi.

Comment: Thanks I already have a patch with the higher version number but my question is that the version number does not appear in the Version column (see screenshot). That column is only populated for a few Microsoft apps, not even for other app updates that use the msi/msp updates for example Adobe Reader.